# download mp3 instead of playing in browser by default?

Tags: browser, download

I have a site where users can stream my music from a flash player or download the individual songs (as mp3s).  Right now if you click on the download links, they just play in the browser.  Can I make it so the download box will pop up by default without either zipping the files making the user rt. click?

I have my index.php page with the links looking like this (pulling file names dynamically from mySQL:

```
<table>
.
.
.
<td>
    <?php include 'Media/' . $row['type'] . '/' . $row['folder_name'] . '/download.php' ?>
</td>
```

and then download.php has this:

```
<div class="downloadCell">
    <h3>Downloads:</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="auto_download.php?path=Media/<?php echo $row['type'] . '/' . $row['folder_name'] ?>/Chemtengure.mp3">Chemtengure</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and I put the auto_download.php in the same directory as index.php:

auto_download.php:

```
$path = $_GET['path'];
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($path));
readfile($path);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to add this HTTP header to your response to make the browser force a download:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your_filename.mp3
```

For example, if you're using PHP on the server side, you can create a script that sends the above header followed by the actual file contents:

```
$path = $_GET['path'];
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($path));
readfile($path);
```

If you call this script `download.php`, then linking to `download.php?path=/path/to/your/file.mp3` will make the browser pop-up a download dialog for `file.mp3`.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit?  I'm afraid I don't quite understand how to code that.  Does that GET just go up in the head section- or it's an include? Or -dang I'm still a noob. :D

Comment: The code You see here is everything You need. Just put it in a php file and point downloads to this file like `<a href="dl.php?path=/mp3s/blink128/fadog.mp3">get this song</a>`

Comment: I'm not getting it to work-I think because I am adding some complexity (pulling download filename dynamically from mySQL.  I have updated my question to share those details.

Comment: doh-I just didn't have php tags in auto_download.php  Works great now.  Thank you guys so much-you're awesome!