# Android: "complete action using..." for custom WebView running ACTION_VIEW intent on an mp3 url

Tags: android, browser, download, webview, mp3

If you open an mp3 url in the Android's browser, you get a "Complete action using..." dialog window with two options: "Music player", or "Browser". If you choose "Browser" it will download the mp3 to the device.

I'm trying to achieve the same from within my application.
I use a WebView with setWebViewClient to a WebViewClient class that has a shouldOverrideUrlLoading method (like in all of the examples). The method checks for an "mp3" extension and startActivity(intent) with a ACTION_VIEW intent on the mp3 url.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
   String lowcaseurl = url.toLowerCase();
   if (lowcaseurl.endsWith(".mp3")) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
       view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
       return true;
    }
    else {
       view.loadUrl(url);
    }
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)
}
```

This **does** show the "Complete action using" dialog window - **but**, if I choose "Browser" then the browser opens but **doesn't get the url!** it just opens the browser and goes to the default "homepage url" (which is google.com in this case)...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show the code you are using for the Intent?

Comment: I edited and added a code snippet that represent the relevant part in my code...

Comment: I believe [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15673) describes the "behind the scenes" reason for this happening, but I have yet to find a solution for it, and am still trying... :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a direct solution, but used a workaround.
I've figured out how to either force the music player to load the url (without giving you a choice of opening it via the browser), or initiate a direct download of the file.

**To force the music player to load a url:**

```
//...considering url contains the url string...
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "audio/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

**To force the initiation of a download:**

You need to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499773/download-mp3-instead-of-playing-in-browser-by-default) technique on the server-side...
but with a few exceptions:

The content-type header should actually contain the right mime-type of the file (and not "application/octet-stream"). Also it is best to also send a "content-length" header with the file size - otherwise there might be problems with the download.

If using aspx:  Response.TransmitFile is better than Response.WriteFile - and in that case Response.Buffer should be set to false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
view.getContext().startActivity( Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open...") );
```

with this you force the dialog "Complete ..."