# Download through php - file does not download completely

Tags: php, wordpress, download

I have set up a Wordpress site that contains the download of an mp3 file. To prevent mp3 files from playing in the browser, but being downloaded instead I have followed these instructions from this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499773/download-mp3-instead-of-playing-in-browser-by-default/3499812#3499812).

Now, the link works but the file is not being downloaded completely. It always downloads about 215 kb instead of the full 14/15 mb. My host tell me they can't help me with this "coding issue". Hope one of you can?

Thanks!
Syl

Comment: post your code. And yes, it is a coding issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, installed a plugin: Easy Media Download. Works!